# Prevent menu key from showing a context menu

Tags: javascript, events, contextmenu

I know that the [keyboard menu key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menu_key) is `keyCode === 93`.

So I have the following code:

```
$(window).on("keydown", document, function(event){
    if (event.keyCode === 93)  {   //context menu
        console.log("context menu key", event);
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Although the event **does** fire, and the `console` does get logged inside the if statement, **but** the context menu still shows even though ***both*** `event.preventDefault();` and `event.stopPropagation();` are present in my code.

Is there any way to **prevent** the menu from being displayed?

Demo for fiddling: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/XJtpc/

---

For those of you who do not know what the "menu" key is:

[image]

Comment: You want to allow the right click context menu to work though? If you don't you should use bind to the contextmenu event instead of keydown.

Comment: Modern day browsers have settings that may prevent you from blocking context menus.

Comment: @aquinas I want the right click menu to work. I do **not** want to block that...

Comment: Can you log the event.keyCode to confirm your keyboard is indeed sending keyCode 93?

Comment: @Bot you obviously did **not** read the OP....

Comment: @Neal your question is not clear, you say the event fires which to me means your keypress fired but doesn't mean your if statement fired.

Comment: @Bot I said everything works. the console.log and all. Did you even look at my demo at all??

Comment: @Neal your question does not say "everything works" and your issue is keyboard specific. Not everyone has a keyboard with a contextmenu key.

Comment: @Neal ---nothing in your question states this, you merely say the event does fire. So Bot is not incorrect in questioning this--- *Ninja'd*

Comment: @rlemon I edited my question to better mirror what happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is kind of dumb but it seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/XJtpc/2/ :)

```
$(function(){
    var lastKey=0;
    $(window).on("keydown", document, function(event){
        lastKey = event.keyCode;            
    });

    $(window).on("contextmenu", document, function(event){
        if (lastKey === 93){
            lastKey=0;
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();
            return false;
        }
    });
});
​
```

Comment: Wow.... ingenious :-)..... Hmmm now I have to try to fig out how to **not** sully the global scope....

Comment: It's not in the global scope, see how I wrapped it in a jquery ready function?

Comment: Yea, but those events do not really need to be in a ready function since they are delegated....

Comment: Well, true, I just tend to wrap things that way when using jQuery, but yes, can just do the (function(){})() trick. Whatever you prefer.

Comment: Just from testing (although it is hard because I don't have a menu key) would this not block the next contextmenu (right click) if they have opened it, and not pressed any keys in the interm? Some browsers may not fire the oncontextmenu event when opening it from the keyboard? or do they? Again this is hard to test on my end.

Comment: @rlemon `contextmenu` is a blocking event. until it is cleared, you cannot do it again. In this case, once the event is over, the contextmenu event is cleared, and you can right click again.

Answer (score 0):

I started with @aquinas' solution but discovered it can be a bit simpler than that.

## Steps

1. Register `keydown` event handler. `e.preventDefault` not required.
2. Register `contextmenu` event handler and just do `e.preventDefault()`

## Example:

```js
// JavaScript
// Register your `ContextMenu` key event handler
document.querySelector('body').onkeydown = (e) => {
  if (e.key === 'ContextMenu') {
    // Do something
  }
}

// Prevent `contextmenu` event default action
document.querySelector('body').oncontextmenu = (e) => e.preventDefault();


// jQuery
// Register your `ContextMenu` key event handler
$('body').on('keydown', (e) => {
  if (e.key === 'ContextMenu') {
    // Do something
  }
});

// Prevent `contextmenu` event default action
$('body').on('contextmenu', (e) => e.preventDefault());
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick is that it's the *keyup* event, not the keydown event that triggers the context menu.  Calling .preventDefault() on a keyup event whose .key is `ContextMenu` will stop it from happening, at least in Chrome and Electron.

That is, you can globally disable the context menu key just with:

```js
window.addEventListener("keyup", function(event){
    if (event.key === "ContextMenu") event.preventDefault();
}, {capture: true})
```

And then monitor the keydown event to trigger your replacement.