# Preventing the start menu from appearing

Tags: javascript, startmenu, windows-key

I'm writing about the age-old problem of trying to keep the start menu from appearing.

I've read everything I've been able to find on the web, including 2 previous stackexchange threads on closely related topics:
[How to disable Windows keys (logo key and menu key) using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16556433/how-to-disable-windows-keys-logo-key-and-menu-key-using-javascript)
and
[Is it possible to block the Windows Key from a web browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18984997/is-it-possible-to-block-the-windows-key-from-a-web-browser)

Now, as people have discussed on those threads, it is not possible to actually block the windows key. I understand that this must be done like that for security, as it would be very dangerous if a script running inside a browser could hijack keys from the operating system. Pretty much for the same reason that a website can never be allowed to go full screen automatically without the user having at least clicked on something.

That's fine.

I'm wondering, however, if instead of trying so desperately to block the windows key, we could instead keep the start menu from appearing. I know it might sound bonkers, but what made me think about it was the solution for dealing with the "context menu" key.  Instead of blocking the key, you can just add  oncontextmenu="return false;" to the body tag, and then you don't even need to worry about the key.

I understand that the difference between the context menu key and the windows key, is that the context menu appears on the browser, whereas the start menu lies outside the scope of the browser, in the UI of the operating system.  But I thought I would ask the question anyway.

For clarity, I'm looking for any solution whatsoever that will allow me to keep the start menu from appearing while my js script is running in the browser, whether it's by blocking the windows key or preventing the start menu from appearing.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable Windows keys (logo key and menu key) using Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16556433/how-to-disable-windows-keys-logo-key-and-menu-key-using-javascript)

Comment: It's not a duplicate. That thread that you mention is cited right at the start of the post.

Comment: Your ask for a solution, yet I see the answer to your question right there on the link, with a question asking for the same thing. Thus, a duplicate.