# want to disable whole keyboard using javascript start key not disabled not even ctrl+d

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have tried to disable whole keyboard using javascript but windows start key is not disabled same way enter key is also not disabled using my script

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  document.onkeydown = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
</script>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19628081/how-to-disable-full-keyboard-keys-using-javascript-or-jquery

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16556433/how-to-disable-windows-keys-logo-key-and-menu-key-using-javascript  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18984997/is-it-possible-to-block-the-windows-key-from-a-web-browser

Comment: You only control what the keys do within the browser, you can't expect the browser to prevent the windows key from working. It would be a major security issue if JS could affect the users entire computer.

Comment: ok is there any other solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you cannot prevent windows key action because after pressing the window key browser doesn't detect it. The reason is that windows key doesn't affect the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
document.onkeydown = function (e) {
        return false;
}
```

Comment: Very unlikely to make a difference.